# DisplayMemberPath on ComboBox not working but Binding seems correct, can't get the DisplayMemberPath to display

Tags: combobox, wcf-binding, generic.xaml

I spent so long on this issue today that I'm posting it as a question and then posting the answer so that **you** can avoid the same kind of frustration that I've gone through for the past 183 minutes.

Here's a simple version of my source code (perhaps yours looks like this)

.xaml (view):

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding WindDirection}" ItemsSource="{Binding WindDirections}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText" IsEditable="False"/>
```

.cs (ViewModel):

```
public class WindDirectionViewModel{
   //I realize that there may be problems in this code, it's not my real code, just a quick sample

   ...code

   List<WindDirectionObject> WindDirections = new List<WindDirectionObject>();
   WindDirectionObject WindDirection = new WindDirectionObject(); 

   ...code

   public string DisplayText = WindDirections.First(x => x.Equals(WindDirection)).DisplayString;

   ...code

}
```

All of the code works *perfectly* and the same (.cs) ViewModel is even displayed correctly in another (.xaml) view, but in *this* view it isn't working correctly. The precise problem is that there's no text in the ComboBox when the view is first opened even though DisplayText has a value! Breakpoints show that the DisplayText value is being correctly calculated and everything, but the value won't display when the view is opened the first time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `DisplayMemberPath` attribute in a .xaml combo box - you **must** place the `ItemsSource` attribute ***before*** the `SelectedItem` attribute in the .xaml... or the `DisplayMemberPath` value isn't displayed.

Before:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding WindDirections}" SelectedItem="{Binding WindDirection}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText" IsEditable="False"/>
```

After:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding WindDirection}" ItemsSource="{Binding WindDirections}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText" IsEditable="False"/>
```

Bam. Works perfectly. This may not solve your problem, but it certainly solved mine...hope this speeds up your development time. :)